# Return value from custom JOptionPane, Java

Tags: java, swing, return, joptionpane

I'm creating a custom class that returns a JFrame, which I then pass into a JOptionPane, because I need two TextFields in the JOptionPane instead of one. Is there any way I can get a return value when OK is pressed?

```
 public static JFrame TwoFieldPane(){

 JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    p.setBackground(background);
    p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10) );
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    p.add(new JLabel(field1), c);
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    p.add(new JLabel(field2), c);
    //p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.ipadx = 100;
    final JTextField username = new JTextField(pretext1);
    username.setBackground(foreground);
    username.setForeground(textcolor);
    p.add(username, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    JTextField password = new JTextField(pretext2);
    password.setBackground(foreground);
    password.setForeground(textcolor);
    p.add(password, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.ipadx = 0;
    JButton okay = new JButton("OK");
    okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            f.setVisible(false);
            //RETURN VALUE HERE
        }
    });
    p.add(okay, c);

    f.add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    f.setVisible(true);
    return f;
}
```

And this is where I'm creating it:

```
try{
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Misc.TwoFieldPane("Server ip: ", "" , "Port: ", ""));
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is a bit unusual. Let me make suggestions:

- Don't use a JFrame for your JOptionPane, that's a bit wacky.
- Avoid overuse of static methods. OOPs is the way to go.
- Create a class that creates your JOptionPane's JPanel for you and that has actual instance fields.
- Give the class getter methods that allow you to query its state after the JOptionPane returns.
- Create your JOptionPane and give it a JPanel created from your class above.
- After the JOptionPane returns, query the object that you've placed in it for its field state.

i.e., an overly simple example...

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
  private JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
  // .... other fields ? ...

  public MyPanel() {
     add(new JLabel("Field 1:");
     add(field1);
  }

  public String getField1Text() {
    return field1.getText();
  }

  // .... other getters for other fields
}
```

... elsewhere in another class ...

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(someComponent, myPanel);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
  String text1 = myPanel.getField1Text(); 
  // ..... String text2 = ...... etc .....
  // .... .use the results here
}
```

As an aside, don't use a JTextField or Strings for passwords, not unless security isn't a concern for your application. Use a JPasswordField and char arrays instead.

Comment: +1 nice new suggestions..but im not sure if i would use a joption pane perhaps just a jdialog

Comment: @nachokk: oh, I use JOptionPanes in this way all the time. They can hold very complex GUI's and display the dialog in a nice compact modal way.

Comment: @nachokk A `JOptionPane` provides a lot of functionality you would have to code for yourself, such as the buttons, and provides a very flexible API to provide very customisable solutions. There are times when you may have no choice but to use a `JDialog`, but there are a lot more where `JOptionPane` is more useful - IMHO

Comment: Thank you, very useful.
An extra thing I put into my soltion is that I did not add getters and setters to the panel, but instead I added getResult() method which returned a custom class containing all the required data from the panel, so it was easier to pass these data to other methods.